# Mark as true if one of the two radio buttons are checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is probably an easy thing to accomplish, but I still haven't figured it out yet.  I have two radio buttons and I want to set state to true if either are checked.

```
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
    if (
        inputs[i].name === 'person' &&
        ((inputs[i].value === 'Employee' && inputs[i].checked === true) ||
        (inputs[i].value === 'Dependent' && inputs[i].checked === true))
       ) {
        inputs[i].style.border = '';
        this.setState({ personFilled: true });
    } else if (
        inputs[i].name === 'person' &&
        ((inputs[i].value === 'Employee' && inputs[i].checked === false) ||
        (inputs[i].value === 'Dependent' && inputs[i].checked === false))) {
        inputs[i].style.border = '2px solid red';
    }
 }
```

As of now, it's always false based on my conditional.

**Radio Button Code**

```
<label>Person</label>
<input
    type='radio'
    className='form-radio'
    name='person'
    id='person'
    value='Employee'
    onChange={gatherFormData}
/>
<span className='label'>Employee</span>
<input
    type='radio'
    className='form-radio'
    name='person'
    value='Dependent'
    onChange={gatherFormData}
/>
<span className='label'>Dependent</span>
```

Comment: Could you also add the code that has the radio buttons?

Comment: Can you please give link to codepen

Comment: How is your `inputs` array created ?

Comment: Instead of a complicated loop, you can do a simple `find`: `if( inputs.find( input => input.name === 'person' && input.checked ) )`. If `inputs` is a `NodeList` you need to convert it to an array like so: `[ ...inputs ].find( ... )`.

Comment: @MaheerAli Please don't ask for *external* code references. Instead, ask the user to make use of StackOverflow snippets. External code reference are **only** acceptable if they require functionality not offered by StackOverflow snippets.

Comment: `i += 1` is identical to `i++`.

Comment: I think you'd be better off holding input values in the component state, have a look at these links https://magnusbenoni.com/radio-buttons-react/ https://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs/

Comment: you can check individual condition while debugging to root out which condition is failing

Comment: @connexo correct, but I'm using eslint and extending on airbnb's plugin, which flags the use of '++' operators.

Comment: @gnusey that was a good read and made sense so started using it, although I still have the name property since I still have other inputs on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set state to false. The code can be simplified to:

```
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
  if (inputs[i].name === 'person') {
    const checked = ((inputs[i].value === 'Employee' && inputs[i].checked) || (inputs[i].value === 'Dependent' && inputs[i].checked));
    inputs[i].style.border = checked ? '' : '2px solid red';
    this.setState({ personFilled: checked });
  }
}
```

Note that you are setting state inside a loop, thus overriding it's value on every iteration. You could store person filled as an array or have different items according the index. If your inputs exists only one time in the UI, you should not use a for loop and refer to them by id, as noted in the comments.

Comment: Great answer!  This helped me work it out a bit better.  I wound up rewriting it to account individually instead of a loop, which solved everythign.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
if ([...inputs].some(x=>x.checked)) { this.setState({ personFilled: true }) };
```

assuming `inputs` is a `NodeList` containing **only** the relevant radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a bit and added some HTML, and it works for me like this:

```js
function handler() { 
    this.setState = function(state) {
        console.log(state);
    }
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
        if (inputs[i].name === 'person' &&
            ((inputs[i].value === 'Employee' && inputs[i].checked === true) ||
            (inputs[i].value === 'Dependent' && inputs[i].checked === true))
        ) {
            inputs[i].style.border = '';
            this.setState({ personFilled: true });
        } else if (inputs[i].name === 'person' &&
            ((inputs[i].value === 'Employee' && inputs[i].checked === false) ||
            (inputs[i].value === 'Dependent' && inputs[i].checked === false))
        ) {
            inputs[i].style.border = '2px solid red';
        }
    }
}

var element = document.querySelector('button')
if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
} else {
    element.attachEvent('onclick', handler);
}
```

```html
<input name="person" type="radio" value="Employee">Employee</input>
<input name="person" type="radio" value="Dependent">Dependent</input>
<button>Submit</button>
```